# Is the room of all convex function with variable dimension $n$ finite dimensional?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Is the room of all convex function with variable dimension $n$ on the same domain finite dimensional and what would be as basis for this room?

Comment: It is not a vector space if the domains are different.

Comment: @Ian its on the same domain i will add it.

Comment: It is not a vector space if the codomains are different either. Also even the convex functions from the reals to the reals are not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Ian ok but it is closed if you only allow positive scalar multiplication and addition, is then there an equivalent to a basis, like a finite set of of convex (basis-like) functions which can represent every convex function by positive scalar multiplication and addition?

Comment: What does "room" mean here?  Space?

Comment: "Positive scalar multiplication" does not really make sense, you can't set up the vector space axioms properly at all without having an actual field of scalars.

Comment: yes you are right the question is nonsense at it is written. What i meant is the following: Can every convex function g written by $g = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i f_i$, where $f_i$ are fixed convex functions and $a_i \in R^+$ are scalars, which can be varied to achieve every g. This is the same as the question is there a Bijection between $\mathbb{R}^+$ and the set of convex functions, so that positive linear combination is preserved by the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, certainly not. Consider, e.g., the domain $U = (0,1)$.

Then, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the functions $x \mapsto x^k$ are convex and linearly independent.